# Launch a process with no IO permissions

Tags: c#, c++, windows, security

How can a program run a process that will only be able to use memory dedicated to that process and return a value, and not any IO including no file system access, registry access, etc. The point is to execute some 3rd party code and get a result without any security/stability risk. Something like `Process.RunSandboxed(processInfo);` .

I would prefer something in C#, but anything would be helpful.

(I've found [AppDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) but that seems to be for managed code only.)

Comment: I think you'd have to create a new user with those policy limitations, and then start the process from the limited user account. That's how I did something similar - it was a while back, but back then I couldn't find anything more elegant. I ended up using a port listener run from the limited account using Task Scheduler which would launch the process I desired when I called the port from the regular account

Comment: This is going to be platform dependent. What platforms are you targeting?

Comment: @Thomas Windows 10 PCs. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Can't be done, not safely, not in Windows.  The only realistic option would be to run the untrusted process in a virtual machine.  (But then there may be licensing issues.)

Comment: This is very difficult, because most system objects have security descriptors that, at the very least, allow all users read access. If you want to, say, prevent `BadWare.exe` from transmitting your browser bookmarks to a remote server, nothing short of virtualization will realistically prevent that, as even specially crafted "anonymous" accounts have rights to do more than you want. There are various technologies for (application) virtualization under Windows (like Sandboxie), but none are included with the OS, unless you count the sandboxing applied to UWP apps.